# Can this be interpreted as one Euler characteristic?

Tags: nt.number-theory, euler-characteristics

Let $[n]:=\{1,\cdots,n\}$. It is known that $\{\log(p) \mid p \text{ is prime }\}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. For a subset $A \subset [n]$ we can consider the matrix $L(A):=(\log(x) \mid x \in A)$ with $\operatorname{rank}_{\mathbb{Q}}(L(A)) = \omega(\prod_{x \in A} x )$, where $\omega(n)$ counts the distinct prime divisors of $n$. Then we have:

$$\sum_{ A \subset [n]} (-1)^{|A|} \omega\left(\prod_{x \in A} x\right) = 0$$

Which denoting $(n;k) := \#\{A \subset [n]\mid \omega(\prod_{x \in A} x) = k\}$ for $k=0,\cdots,n$ might be rewritten as:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k (n;k)=0$$

My question is, if this last quantity can be interpreted as one Euler characteristic [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Topological_definition]?

Here are some numbers $(n;k)$ computed:

```
1 [2]
2 [2, 2]
3 [2, 4, 2]
4 [2, 8, 6, 0]
5 [2, 10, 14, 6, 0]
6 [2, 10, 30, 22, 0, 0]
7 [2, 12, 40, 52, 22, 0, 0]
8 [2, 20, 80, 108, 46, 0, 0, 0]
9 [2, 24, 148, 232, 106, 0, 0, 0, 0]
10 [2, 24, 180, 488, 330, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
11 [2, 26, 204, 668, 818, 330, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
12 [2, 26, 332, 1308, 1714, 714, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
13 [2, 28, 358, 1640, 3022, 2428, 714, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
14 [2, 28, 390, 2280, 5646, 5884, 2154, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1, I had never seen this identity pretty cool it if I understand correctly it gives 0 because it is an inclusion-exclusion formula, I read this question and came back to see if someone answered but it was deleted so is nice too see it back

Comment: @DanielD. thanks for your comment

Comment: we can write $\omega( \prod_{x\in A} x ) $ as the sum over $p<n$ of $1$ if $p$ divides $x$ for some $x$ in $A$ and $0$ otherwise. Exchanging the order of summation proves your identity. This makes me think, if it's an Euler characteristic, this will just be a space that is a disjoint union over the primes.

Comment: Euler characteristic is based on the equation between the alternative sums of ranks of two kinds of groups (chains vs homology). Do you have two seemingly unrelated kinds of objects, etc. ?

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\cdot\binom nk = 0\ $ because $(n-1)$-simplex is acyclic. Also, $\ \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\cdot 2^{n-k}\cdot\binom nk = 1\ $ because $n$-cube is acyclic, etc.

Comment: It do not see how exactly "rewriting" of the formulae works here, but they can be viewed as an application of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) applied to the sets $$\{x\in [n]\ :\  p_i\mid x\}.$$